# How to change the user name who push with deploy key to github

Tags: github

In my organization of GitHub, my team member (suppose that his name is `John`)  added a deploy key to repository.

We have a bot user account. Suppose this account name is `BotUser` and email is `bot@example.com`. I put private key (which is pair of deploy key `John` added) to `/home/botuser/.ssh/` and configure `/home/botuser/.gitconfig` like this:

```
[user]
    name = BotUser
    email = bot@exampe.com
```

And pushed tags (command is `git tag -a tag_name -m 'message' && git push --tags`) automatically by this `BotUser` setting. But GitHub displays that the user who created the tag is `John`. The message of news feed page (url is `https://github.com/`) is like `John created tag tag_name at org_name/repo_name`.

But int tag page (url is `https://github.com/org_name/repo_name/releases/tag/tag_name`), the tag is supposed to be created by `BotUser`. The page shows like `BotUser tagged this an hour ago`.

We want to show as `BotUser` also in news feed page. How can I do this?

**[UPDATED]**

In this case, we use `deploy key` to push tags. So I cannot set GitHub account name of it.

My question is "how can I set (change) the `pusher` name which pushed with `deploy key`".

Comment: I've send this question to the GitHub support and got an answer. According to it, the account name who add a deploy key is showed up as the "Pusher". So I removed and added again the same deploy key.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [environment variables](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Committing) (just for the `git tag` command):

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
```

That way, the author associated to the pushed tag would be the right one.

Comment: I tried `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` instead of `GIT_AUTHOR_*` and I can overwrite `Tagger`. But `pusher` is still not be changed.

Comment: Actually, you should set both author and committer

Comment: Thanks. I tried again with set both author and committer. But `pusher` is still not be changed. Message like `pushed by John` (which is not a value of `GIT_*_NAME`) is still displayed on news feed page of GitHub.

Comment: Yes, it would still be pushed by john, but at least it is set by the botuser. To change the push author, you would need a github account named botuser, with its own password or ssh key.

Comment: In our case, we use `deploy key` to push tags. So I cannot set account name because the user has no account.

Comment: I understand. That explains why you see john. Maybe github support has more information